# creation of static library confusion

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode4.2, static-libraries

I tried creating static library by following the apple document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW1.

I created library and when I tried to link library to my app, in app target->build phase->Link Binary With Libraries, I am not able to see the library which I created in the list of frameworks and libraries.

Does it mean that library is not created or am I missing something important to make it work? Please help me out in finding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
app target->build phase->Link Binary With Libraries
```

you see those libraries/ frameworks which are available in iOS SDK.
To link to the library created by you, click on `+` sign at the bottom left and then `Add Other..`
Browse to the .a file you have created, Click `Open.`

PS: To save your .a extension, after building your `Cocoa Touch Static Library` project , 
under Products, you will see, .a file. Right Click-> Show in Finder -> Copy to some location

Comment: thanks I just dragged the corresponding .h and .a file from the location and it was automatically update to build phase.

Comment: I added a class function sumOfnum1:andNum2 and tried to call that method resulting in Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AddandSubOpp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in _AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 error. Can u help me out!  I created reference of .a file from iphonesimulator since I am using for simulator.

Comment: When you created the library, what device have you selected? Are you testing on simulator or real device? Please clean build the next time you build the library.

Comment: thanks it all worked. I was adding wrong .a file. I cleaned all and created a .a file for simulator and linked it. Finally it worked. thanks

Comment: I am testing in simulator only. I was using some other old .a file. There were so many files created. So cleaned all and gave a rebuild with iphone simulator as scheme and by linking to proper .a file it worked. thanks.